# do I need to remove datatable before filling it again with a different query?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am filling a datatable called 'Reports', then clearing it and filling it with a different query. The problem is, when I fill it the second time, the datatable is not filled out correctly. There are extra columns and it is not in the same order as my query. I am using the dataset visualizer to see the contents of the datatable while i am debugging. Is there something I need to be doing to the datatable other than

```
ds.table("Reports").clear
```

before i fill the table again? I figured out if I remove the table completely before I fill it again, then the table is filled out right the second time.

Current code structure goes something like this when filling the table the second time:

```
ds.tables("Reports").clear

reportSQL = "select field1, field2 from table"
daReports = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(reportSQL, con)
daReports.Fill(ds, "Reports")
```

At this point, the table is filled out incorrectly. It only works when i add this before i fill the table:

```
ds.tables.remove("Reports")
```

Is this the right way to go about filling a datatable multiple times with different queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ds.table("Reports").clear` only clears rows collection from the datatable (similar to `ds.table("Reports").Rows.clear`). In addition to that you need to clear columns collection:

```
ds.table("Reports").Columns.Clear()
```

This will get rid of extra columns

Comment: ah ha! That makes much more sense. Thanks!